# JTX/Workflow Manager dependencies to control workflow

Tags: arcgis-desktop, workflow, arcgis-workflow-manager

When creating a new job in JTX, one of the required fields (under "Additional Information") tab we have is "Asset Type". The three choices for "Asset Type" are "Water", "Sewer" and "Water and Sewer". My question is, is it possible to setup JTX where depending on the Asset Type, certain step(s) in the workflow will be skipped. For example, if I choose Water as my asset type, I may want to skip a certain step and if I choose sewer as the asset type I may want to skip a different step.

Answer (score 1):

As defined in the [help](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#/Essential_Workflow_Manager_vocabulary/003800000003000000/), each **Job** is defined by a **Job Type**, which has a defined by a **Workflow**, which is composed of multiple **Steps**.  Since your workflow seems different for each "Asset Type", you will need to create three (3) Job Types with their respective workflow.

I've used [Token](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#/Using_Tokens/00380000002m000000/) in the past to configure which Map Document (MXD) would open based on a user selected variable while using the same Job Type, but your case seems more involving then that.

Comment: Eric, thanks for the response. Creating a new workflow was my last option if nothing else worked. Since posting, I've figured out a workaround for this issue by connecting steps around a step(s) to be skipped.  Therefore, when a sewer job comes up, at the step prior to the step to be skipped, the owner has the option to move to the next step or skip it and move to the appropriate step.

Comment: @Steve, that a neat trick.  Glad you find a solution.